# Can any dynamic language can write the some prog like the book<Type-Driven Development with idris>'s Chapter6's datastore?

Tags: python, ruby, idris

The book's Chapter6's datastore:

```
module Main

import Data.Vect

infixr 5 .+.

data Schema = SString | SInt | (.+.) Schema Schema

SchemaType : Schema -> Type
SchemaType SString = String
SchemaType SInt = Int
SchemaType (x .+. y) = (SchemaType x, SchemaType y)

record DataStore where
  constructor MkData
  schema : Schema
  size : Nat
  items : Vect size (SchemaType schema)

addToStore : (store : DataStore) -> SchemaType (schema store) -> DataStore
addToStore (MkData schema size store) newitem = MkData schema _ (addToData store)
  where
    addToData : Vect oldsize (SchemaType schema) -> Vect (S oldsize) (SchemaType schema)
    addToData [] = [newitem]
    addToData (x :: xs) = x :: addToData xs

setSchema : (store : DataStore) -> Schema -> Maybe DataStore
setSchema store schema = case size store of
                              Z => Just (MkData schema _ [])
                              S k => Nothing

data Command : Schema -> Type where
     SetSchema : Schema -> Command schema
     Add : SchemaType schema -> Command schema
     Get : Integer -> Command schema
     Quit : Command schema


parsePrefix : (schema : Schema) -> String -> Maybe (SchemaType schema, String)
parsePrefix SString input = getQuoted (unpack input)
  where
    getQuoted : List Char -> Maybe (String, String)
    getQuoted ('"' :: xs)
        = case span (/= '"') xs of
               (quoted, '"' :: rest) => Just (pack quoted, ltrim (pack rest))
               _ => Nothing
    getQuoted _ = Nothing

parsePrefix SInt input = case span isDigit input of
                              ("", rest) => Nothing
                              (num, rest) => Just (cast num, ltrim rest)
parsePrefix (schemal .+. schemar) input
    = case parsePrefix schemal input of
           Nothing => Nothing
           Just (l_val, input') =>
                case parsePrefix schemar input' of
                     Nothing => Nothing
                     Just (r_val, input'') => Just ((l_val, r_val), input'')

parseBySchema : (schema : Schema) -> String -> Maybe (SchemaType schema)
parseBySchema schema x = case parsePrefix schema x of
                              Nothing => Nothing
                              Just (res, "") => Just res
                              Just _ => Nothing

parseSchema : List String -> Maybe Schema
parseSchema ("String" :: xs)
    = case xs of
           [] => Just SString
           _ => case parseSchema xs of
                     Nothing => Nothing
                     Just xs_sch => Just (SString .+. xs_sch)
parseSchema ("Int" :: xs)
    = case xs of
           [] => Just SInt
           _ => case parseSchema xs of
                     Nothing => Nothing
                     Just xs_sch => Just (SInt .+. xs_sch)
parseSchema _ = Nothing

parseCommand : (schema : Schema) -> String -> String -> Maybe (Command schema)
parseCommand schema "add" rest = case parseBySchema schema rest of
                                      Nothing => Nothing
                                      Just restok => Just (Add restok)
parseCommand schema "get" val = case all isDigit (unpack val) of
                                    False => Nothing
                                    True => Just (Get (cast val))
parseCommand schema "quit" "" = Just Quit
parseCommand schema "schema" rest
    = case parseSchema (words rest) of
           Nothing => Nothing
           Just schemaok => Just (SetSchema schemaok)
parseCommand _ _ _ = Nothing

parse : (schema : Schema) -> (input : String) -> Maybe (Command schema)
parse schema input = case span (/= ' ') input of
                          (cmd, args) => parseCommand schema cmd (ltrim args)

display : SchemaType schema -> String
display {schema = SString} item = show item
display {schema = SInt} item = show item
display {schema = (y .+. z)} (iteml, itemr) = display iteml ++ ", " ++
                                              display itemr

getEntry : (pos : Integer) -> (store : DataStore) ->
           Maybe (String, DataStore)
getEntry pos store
    = let store_items = items store in
          case integerToFin pos (size store) of
               Nothing => Just ("Out of range\n", store)
               Just id => Just (display (index id (items store)) ++ "\n", store)

processInput : DataStore -> String -> Maybe (String, DataStore)
processInput store input
    = case parse (schema store) input of
           Nothing => Just ("Invalid command\n", store)
           Just (Add item) =>
              Just ("ID " ++ show (size store) ++ "\n", addToStore store item)
           Just (SetSchema schema') =>
              case setSchema store schema' of
                   Nothing => Just ("Can't update schema when entries in store\n", store)
                   Just store' => Just ("OK\n", store')
           Just (Get pos) => getEntry pos store
           Just Quit => Nothing

main : IO ()
main = replWith (MkData (SString .+. SString .+. SInt) _ []) "Command: " processInput
```

it can define scheme of a "database" with String and Int in runtime:

```
Command: schema String String Int
OK
Command: add "Rain Dogs" "Tom Waits" 1985
ID 0
Command: add "Fog on the Tyne" "Lindisfarne" 1971
ID 1
Command: get 1
"Fog on the Tyne", "Lindisfarne", 1971
Command: quit
```

I want to know if any dynamic language like ruby or python can do the same thing?In the static language,the scheme must be defined before the compile.

Thanks!

Comment: Any Turing complete language (like Python and Ruby) can do this.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Funnily enough, Idris is not Turing-complete. Or, more precisely, you, as the programmer, have to prove to the compiler that your program always terminates, and if you can't prove that, then you lose some of the features of Idris's type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a static type system is to *reject ill-typed programs*. In other words, a static type system *prevents* you from writing programs.

So, if you can write a program in a language with a static type system, then you can also write that same program in a language without a static type system.

Note that this is an extremely simplified explanation. I am well aware of the power of static type systems, and I love to use them. However, when it comes down to it, a static type system never *enables* you to write a program you couldn't otherwise write, it only *prevents* you from writing programs that are not well-typed.

> In the static language, the scheme must be defined before the compile

This can be alleviated by something like [F#](https://fsharp.org/)'s [Type Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/). Type Providers are code that runs during the compilation process and can generate type information that is not statically available in the program source text.

For example, there is a [`SQLProvider`](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) which can connect to a SQL database, read out its schema, and generate F# types from the schema.

But, of course, all of this still happens at compile time. The generated types will be the ones *from the time you compiled the program*, not when you actually connect to the database, and if the database schema changes, you have to re-run the type provider to generate new types.